# Nagios reports host as down, services as OK

Tags: nagios

I am trying to monitor a remote server .Nagios reports host as down,but the services of host are OK.

Comment: What is the host definition? What are the service definitions? What are the command definitions in use?

Comment: I think this is happening because I am not able to ping from either server.Check_PING is not working as it says Service is not scheduled to be checked...

Comment: Host checks and service checks are separate things.  If you have a host check that does a ping and the remote machine is blocking ICMP requests, then the host check will fail.  If that same host has a service associated with it that is using some other method (NRPE agent, HTTP check, etc.) that is not blocked, then it is possible to have a service check succeed while the host check fails.

Comment: Thanks.This helps!

Comment: what is the solution to this

Comment: Can you ping the host from the nagios server command line? What have you tried so far to solve the problem?

Comment: No I am not able to ping ..it gives

Comment: 4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +2 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3650ms

Comment: I am new to linux thing. what should be the next step so that I am able to ping

Comment: Did you try changing from 'check_ping' to 'check_nrpe'?

Comment: /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_ping -H hostname   -w 3000.0,80% -c 5000.0,100% -p 5
CRITICAL - Packet Filtered (hostname)


/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H hostname
NRPE v2.5.1

Comment: above is response for both scenarios

Comment: What sort of service checks are you running against the host?